# Using "culture" in CodeProvider?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm using VBCodeProvider, but my question also goes for CSharpCodeProvider.

Take this code:

```
Dim d As Decimal = 1.23
```

In Denmark, we switch . and , - so this would be:

```
Dim d As Decimal = 1,23
```

Is it possible to tell VBCodeProvider or CSharpCodeProvider to use culture (Danish) when running the code?

Thanks

**Update:**

Like I can do this...

```
.ToString("C2", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("da-DK"))
```

I would like to do something like this...

```
Dim code = "Return 1,23 * 1,23"
Dim cp As VBCodeProvider = New VBCodeProvider
Dim params As CompilerParameters = New CompilerParameters
Dim results As CompilerResults
params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.dll")
params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.xml.dll")
params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.data.dll")
params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll")
params.CompilerOptions = "/t:library"
results = cp.CompileAssemblyFromSource(params, code, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("da-DK"))
```

... so I can run code in danish format.

Comment: Why this question? What is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve? Numeric literals are *not* culture-specific in any programming language, or it would be impossible to compile source code in different countries. The compiler should work with `1.23` in any locale

Comment: No, the VB.NET language is not culture sensitive.  Having a program fail to compile just because the source code was moved from one machine to another would be a rather horrible feature.  The language spec demands that you use a period, not a comma.

Comment: I'm not sure I am explaing myself properly ... I don't want VS to use culture, I want to run some code - on the fly - (see my update above) as danish culture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do what you want.

No matter what culture your machine is running,

```
Dim d As Decimal = 1,23
```

**is not valid VB.Net**. The [Language Specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms234437.aspx) is clear on this (my emphasis):

> 2.4.3 Floating-Point Literals
>
> A floating-point literal is an integer literal followed by an optional
>   decimal point (**the ASCII period character**) and mantissa, and an
>   optional base 10  exponent.

You **must** use `.` as the decimal point in floating-point literals. You can no more use the Danish decimal point than a French programmer could say

```
Dimensionné d Comme Nombre Décimal = 1,23
```

or a Chinese programmer could say

```
尺寸 d 十進制數 壹點貳參
```

(apologies to anyone who can read Mandarin, I used wiktionary for this...)

---

I note that I do have a vague memory that at one time, various language-specific versions of Excel VBA did exist! But those days are long gone.